# Why can't Azure B2C find the owner account when trying to login

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a B2C directory in Azure AD.  It added my AD User from the main directory to that directory when creating the directory.  I have configured it to utilize the signup-signin policy and that appears to be working because I was able to create an account and it logged me as the account was created.  It is my understanding that the account that creates the directory is considered the owner of the directory and is identified as any other user.  Is that correct?  Anyway, I would think that I could log in as that user but it cannot even find the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial user that creates an Azure AD B2C tenant is associated as **a guest user**, via the Global Administrator role, with the Azure AD B2C directory.

A Global Administrator user can administer the Azure AD B2C directory, policies, and other Azure AD B2C settings.

A guest user cannot be authenticated by a sign-in policy because this policy is scoped to users that are created as [local and social account users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I decided to use B2C because the application we are moving to Azure PaaS requires allowing the user to provide a external corporate email account to connect.  Would you suggest using a different directory type for the requirement?  If you would, would that suggestion allow third part logins if we were to move in that direction?

Comment: I would also like to ask if a different directory type would allow the various customization afforded by a B2C directory, to include user signup / signin?

Comment: You can consider either [an Azure AD multi-tenant application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview) to accept sign-ins from any Azure Active Directory tenant or [an Azure AD B2C custom policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom). For the first option, you implement sign-up by invoking [the consent flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent).

Comment: I am searching for this answer but if you could be kind and answer it that would be much appreciated. @ChrisPadgett Can a root global administrator manage all tenant directories in all aspects?